# android application class oncreate taking time

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have to initialize data for Android Application, initialization does a service call, it is taking time. I have coded all the initialization in Application.onCreate().  It is taking time to reach Activity.onCreate() (launcher activity) I can see the black screen for some time, then loading view is appearing which is in an Acitivy.onCreate().

Is there anyway to show the splash screen when the Application oncreate is running.

Comment: please post some of your code :)

Answer (score 0):

First load your Activity then in on create using **AsyncTask** call and initialize your variables. So that you can avoid the black screen.
You can get more information about AsyncTask from here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Good example from here

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Hope this helps you

Comment: yeah i thought about it. I also tried this. But i am having home screen widget for my app. The widget also needs all the data to be initialized.